# Regarding AngularJS Routing in visual studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

I'm new to angularJS and have been working on a tutorial in visual studio on angularjs routing, but even though I change the url link, the ng-view doesn't change.
This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">
<a href="#/home">home</a>
<a href="#/anotherpage">another page</a>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
    template: 'Home'
})
.when('/anotherpage', {
    template: 'another page'
})
.otherwise({
    template: 'index'
});
});
```

Even though I change the url to /index.html#/home, the content in the div is always 'index'. can anyone suggest any solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

change the html as below it should work.

```
  <a href="#!home">home</a>
  <a href="#!anotherpage">another page</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
```